# C++: Inheriting from template class with possible varying constructor arguments

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Suppose we have the following sample classes:

```
class A { 
  public:
    explicit A(int foo) { } 

    void test() {
      cout << "I'm in A" << endl;
    }   
};

class B { 
  public:
    explicit B(string bar) { } 

    void test() {
      cout << "I'm in B" << endl;
    }   
};
```

I would like to define a child class to inherit from a templatized class that
could be specialized as one of either A or B. The problem I'm facing is that A
and B have different constructor arguments, so building Child's constructor is
proving to be a bit vexing. Things work if I do something like the following:

```
template <class ParentClass>
class Child : public ParentClass {
  public:
    Child<B>() : ParentClass("foo") {
    }   
};

int main() {
  Child<B> c;
  c.test();
  return 0;
}
```

However, I'd like to also be able to do something like `Child<A> c`. Is this
possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want a default constructor for `Child`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may specialize for each class:

```
template <class ParentClass>
class Child : public ParentClass {
  public:
    Child();
};

template <>
Child<A>::Child() : A(42) {}

template <>
Child<B>::Child() : B("42") {}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe3ded67f6f262aa)

Answer (score 3):

You can try a templated constructor as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    explicit A(int foo) { }

    void test() {
        cout << "I'm in A" << endl;
    }
};

class B {
public:
    explicit B(string bar) { }

    void test() {
        cout << "I'm in B" << endl;
    }
};

template <class Parent>
class Child
: public Parent {

public:
    template <class... Args>
    Child(Args... args)
    : Parent(args...) {

    }
};

int main() {
    Child<A> a_child(42);
    Child<B> b_child("42");
    a_child.test();
    b_child.test();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a delegating constructor if you want to let the user decides the parameters:

```
template <class ParentClass>
class Child : public ParentClass {
public:
    using ParentClass::ParentClass;
};
```